# How to set JVM option on Windows Java Plugin

Tags: java, applet, jvm

On Windows I tried below two but nothing worked.

> Java Control Panel / Java / Java Runtime Settings / View / User / Runtime Parameters 
>      -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
>
> set JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
>
> Java Console still prints out
>
> ```
> file.encoding = MS949
> ```

Comment: `Environment Variables` may be?

Comment: What is about running `jconsole -J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you nedd a global JVM option:

try to add `JAVA_OPTS`to you windows environment.

```
set JAVA_OPTS=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 %JAVA_OPTS%
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing runtime parameters does not work with jre whose versions is > `7u17`

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=8016005

It should be fixed in jre `7u40`.

I had to downgrade to `7u17`.

Hope it helps...